# Fourier series and it is applications

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

First of all I'm not specialized in physics or in applied mathematics in general.

But as far as I know that the fourier series applications depend on the length." For example the length of the wave" and other length of things.

My question is: are there applications in Math\Physics (diiferential equations , ODE, or partial) where the change is in the angle not in the length?

I think that all of the change could be expressed as the change in the angle
For example instead of dealing with the wave length we can deal directly with the change in the angles of the curve that constructed the wave.

is that correct?

and is there any benefit of dealing with angles instead of dealing with the length in such applications?

Comment: You want to describe the curve by its curvature (angle change per length) and then try to find some useful information from the Fourier transform of the curvature function? Or directly by the angle of the tangent as in $\dot x(s)=\cos(\phi(s))$, $\dot y(s)=\sin(\phi(s))$?

Comment: Actually you have been exactly described both of my thoughts

Comment: In the second case if we want to describe the curve by the angle of tangent, would be useful for some applications? , and for the first case when we have the ratio of n/L in fourier to be the angle + number of rotations times $ \pi $ would this be benfeical in some applications?

Comment: Yes, the parametrization by angle is used in models for a bending string, or in the control of flying objects, and others that do not presently come to mind. But I'm uncertain if there is any use in the expansion in harmonic components. I would think that a wavelet transform would find an easier justification.

Comment: Okay thank you, could you give me a reference for such differential equations  where I can use the representing of the change of n/L to be the change in the angle + $\pi $ times the rotations